# Convert SQL to LINQ with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq

I'm stumped trying to convert the following sql to linq:

```
SELECT t.* FROM(SELECT mwfieldid,MAX([TimeStamp]) AS MaxValue, BatchDocumentID
   FROM mw_BatchField 
   GROUP BY mwfieldid,BatchDocumentID) x
  JOIN mw_BatchField t ON x.mwfieldid = t.mwfieldid
   AND x.MaxValue = t.TimeStamp
   and x.BatchDocumentID = t.BatchDocumentID
```

So far I had to convert it to a stored proc to get it to work. I'd rather know how to write this correctly in linq. I tried using a sql to linq converter (http://www.sqltolinq.com/) which produced this code that had errors in it: (Are these converters any good? It didn't seem to produce anything useful with a few tries.)

```
From x In ( 
    (From mw_BatchFields In db.mw_BatchFields
    Group mw_BatchFields By 
      mw_BatchFields.MWFieldID,
      mw_BatchFields.BatchDocumentID
     Into g = Group 
    Select 
      MWFieldID,
      MaxValue = CType(g.Max(Function(p) p.TimeStamp),DateTime?),
      BatchDocumentID)
    )
Join t In db.mw_BatchFields
      On New With { .MWFieldID = CInt(x.MWFieldID), .MaxValue = CDate(x.MaxValue), .BatchDocumentID = CInt(x.BatchDocumentID) }
  Equals New With { .MWFieldID = t.MWFieldID, .MaxValue = t.TimeStamp, .BatchDocumentID = t.BatchDocumentID }
Select 
  BatchFieldID = t.BatchFieldID,
  BatchDocumentID = t.BatchDocumentID,
  MWFieldID = t.MWFieldID,
  TimeStamp = t.TimeStamp,
  value = t.value,
  DictionaryValue = t.DictionaryValue,
  AutoFilled = t.AutoFilled,
  employeeID = t.employeeID
```

Seems like a lot of code for such a simple query, and it doesn't compile.

Comment: What compiler error do you get?  It's not that much more code if you take into account the fact that * has to be decompressed and all of the extra keywords that VB requires.

Comment: Looks ok to me.  What compiler error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: Here is a link to an image showing the errors: [link](http://imgur.com/ECKACcY), as you can see it is expecting "equals" right after the "Join t In db.mw_BatchFields" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for every combination of mwfieldid and BatchDocumentID you want all columns of the row with the highest TimeStamp? This is something which is much easier to express in LINQ than SQL so I'm not surprised that an automated converter is making a meal of it.

You should be able to do:

```
Mw_BatchFields.GroupBy(x => new { x.Mwfieldid, x.BatchDocumentId })
    .SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.TimeStamp == x.Max(z => z.TimeStamp)))
```

This (like your SQL) will return multiple rows per grouping key if there is more than one row in the group that shares the same maximum TimeStamp. If you only want row per key, you could use:

```
Mw_BatchFields.GroupBy(x => new { x.Mwfieldid, x.BatchDocumentId })
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First())
```

**Edit:**
Sorry, just twigged that you're working in VB, not C#, so not quite what you were looking for, but if you can live with the lambda syntax style, I think the above can be translated as:

```
Mw_BatchFields.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {x.Mwfieldid, x.BatchDocumentId}).Select(Function(x) x.OrderByDescending(Function(y) y.TimeStamp).First())
```

and:

```
Mw_BatchFields.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {x.Mwfieldid, x.BatchDocumentId}).SelectMany(Function(x) x.Where(Function(y) y.TimeStamp = x.Max(Function(z) z.TimeStamp)))
```